# Creating new keystore Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keystore, android-keystore, android-app-signing

When I want to create a new Key store from Build > Generate Signed Bundle or APK it gives me this error in Android Studio:

```
Warning:  Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -keypass value.
```

What is the solution for this error in Android Studio ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved when I use the same password in key store and alias